# Wireless not working anymore on Acer Aspire 6930G when I upgraded to 12.04

Tags: wireless, 12.04, drivers

I have been using Ubuntu for a long time and I have never encountered any driver related issues. However after I upgraded my Ubuntu to the latest version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, wireless is not working anymore. My machine is Acer Aspire 6930G. The output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:8b:ab:ca:75  
          inet addr:192.168.1.37  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:8bff:feab:ca75/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23522506 (23.5 MB)  TX bytes:3213803 (3.2 MB)
          Interrupt:47 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:385015 (385.0 KB)  TX bytes:385015 (385.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:fa:1a:6c:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.35  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:faff:fe1a:6ca8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32326 (32.3 KB)  TX bytes:12005 (12.0 KB)
```

Comment: I'll give this my upvote. I'm also having the very same problem with my Lenovo G470. :(

Comment: When you run the output of ifconfig, what do you see? Also does Restricted Drivers show anything?

Comment: I added output of ifconfiq to the question. Restricted Drivers only shows graphics drivers.

Comment: I have exactly the same computer and the wireless works perfectly fine after the upgrade to precise, thus, it is not hardware-related. Do you use iptables or ufw ?

Comment: I do not even know what iptables and ufw are. Can you tell me how can i check them?

Comment: Ok. Iptables is your firewall (off by default) and ufw a more user-friendly application to manage it. If you don't know what they are, chances are big that they are not enabled (and will not be the cause of your problem).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: It would help if we knew the model # of the wireless card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and this helped.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Installing_STA_drivers

Note: In my case at this step  'System > Administration > Hardware/Additional Drivers,'  The driver failed to install correctly, but it starting working after rebooting the laptop.

Good luck.